# Reports - Calculation

Tags: reporting

I have a custom flow where tasks are being assigned to every user of a public group, since i cannot assign a task via Apex to a group directly.

On Activity object i have a custom field that for every "set" of tasks, is unique. I want, in a report for the Administrator, to have the ability to see the Pending Tasks for Example. But the problem is that if i go to see the number of pending tasks it will be (Number of Pending Tasks)*(number of users in the group). So i want a report to see the number of tasks but one time for every unique value of my custom field. Is there any clever way to achieve this ?

Elaboration: User edits an account, saves the record and a record of a custom object is being saved via Apex. Then, i get the id of this record and i insert (again via Apex) as many tasks as the members of the public group, in status pending and in a custom field i insert the id of this record. So the thing is, i need to know the number of pending tasks for the team... But not the total number of tasks. Just the total number of UNIQUE tasks.

Example: The public group has 2 members. Me and another user. I edit an account, save the changes and the tasks are being created. One for me and one for the other user of the team. The admin needs to know the number of pending tasks per custom record, so in this case he should see 1. Not 2 that the report total number of pending tasks would show.

Comment: This question needs elaboration with some tangible examples as it is fairly broad. Please use [edit]

Comment: I edited the question. Thanks

Comment: in SOQL, you have `SELECT COUNT_DISTINCT(custom field) FROM Task WHERE ..`; for reports, though, you can use the [Power Of One trick](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063000000048RbAAI)